# Output javascript to bootstrap 3 modal dialogue

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap-3

I've got the following code, which is working fine...

But I'd like the web page that is returned when the widget is clicked to appear in a modal popup.

I am using Bootstrap 3

Tried a few things, but not making any progress, can someone help?

```
<div class='login_box'>
        loading...
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">

        var clientkey = '@System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ClientKey"]'

        $(document).ready(function () {


            Widget.login({ 'app_key': Clientkey }, function (widget_html) {

                $('login_box').html(widget_html);
            });
        });
    </script>
```

Comment: I'm assuming that login_box is a modal, try $('#login_box').modal('show'); http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals

Comment: I've tried that, the login box isn't a modal looking at the javascript, looks like I have got some editing to do..